# Contar elementos na tela

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de eu contar os elementos na tela, por exemplo uma função que listasse a quantidade de `<li>` dispostos na minha página web.

Como eu poderia fazer isto? E como funcionaria está função?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
function contar(what){
   return document.querySelectorAll(what).length; 
}
```

Por exemplo nesta página usando `contar('li')` dá 92. Com esta função podes passar um seletor de CSS como `ul li.nome` que também funciona.

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/x082v700/

Comment: +1 A resposta ficou melhor ainda, porque tem a função

Comment: É a melhor forma de se fazer, acredito eu.

Answer (score 5):

Com javascript puro você pode fazer assim:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').length
```

`length` retornará a quantidade de items presentes no seu documento.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o JQuery para fazer isso, por exemplo

```
$('li').size();
```

você também pode colocar uma classe na li tipo `<li class="item">` e utilizar

```
$('.item').size();
```

assim não corre o risco de pegar todas as li presente na página.

Answer (score 4):

Sua melhor solução sem dúvidas será com o `.length` e como é uma coisa tão simples nem tem a necessidade do `jquery`.

Eu apenas mudaria uma questão, o seletor, em alguns testes nos navegadores o  `document.getElementsByTagName` se apresenta mais rápido que  `document.querySelectorAll`.

[getElementsByTagName vs querySelectorAll](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname)

Então se pegar todos os elementos li e contar e o seu problema indicaria algo assim:

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
document.write('Quantidade de li: ' + li);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Desta forma é possível, o script irá varrer todos os elementos `li`.

@Edit: Forma simplificada.

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
document.writeln('Existem ' + elementos.length);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

@Edit: implementação do count.

```js
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var count = 0;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementos, function(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  count++;
});
document.writeln('Existem ' + count);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ten mais facil, faz assim

```
$('li').length
```

pronto, simples facil e limpo

Comment: Mais bonito visualmente porém é utilizando Jquery a versão que foi colocado como a melhor resposta, soluciona o problema sem utilizar mais nenhuma biblioteca

Comment: Sim, hj eu evito usar jquery, 5 anos depois kkkkk

Answer (score -1):

tenta isso com Jquery:

```
 var i = 0;
 $('li').each(function(){
     i++                         
 });
 alert(i);
```

Comment: Apesar de alguns esconderem seus rostos e não falar quando dão negativos, eu vou falar. Eu dei -1 porque essa não é uma boa ideia, considerando que o jQuery tem métodos próprios para isso. Com `size` e a prioriedade `length`.